# killing dwm leaves left over processes

Tags: xorg, dwm

I am using dwm on an opensuse box where I don't have root permissions. 
I launch dwm using "custom session" from KDM, which executes my `.xsession`.

```
$ cat .xsession
exec ~/bin/startdwm

cat ~/bin/startdwm
#!/bin/bash

xscreensaver -nosplash &
ivman &
while true
do
xsetroot -name "$(date +"%H:%M:%S|%d-%m")"
sleep 1 
done &
exec /home/nahum/bin/dwm > .dwm.log
```

The problem I have is the following:
I exit this session with WIN+SHIFT+Q, I have always a process left over ivman and sleep. 
How do I kill them?

Thanks, Oz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing  the `exec` there's not much you can do. Without that, you could save the background PIDs twice and kill them later when dwm terminates.

```
ivman &
IVMAN_PID=$!
...
/home/nahum/bin/dwm > .dwm.log
kill $IVMAN_PID
```